# How to pass if it is nonetype object?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have built a bot which pulls matches' info from HLTV. Problem is, before 10 am there isn't being any live match. When my bot tries to pull the page's links it gives error.

I tried to ignore it like:

```
if links is None:
    pass
```

Returns me as:

```
'Nonetype' object has no attribute find_all('a')
```

I tried try and except but when i use try and except it takes all the code again and again. I mean think like loop in loop. :D Which is annoying. Is there any way to solve it?

My code is here but you wont take that error because it passed 10 am :D

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, datetime
matchlinks_lm = []
r = requests.get('https://hltv.org/matches')
sauce = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
for links in soup.find('div', class_='live-matches').find_all('a'):
    matchlinks_lm.append('https://hltv.org' + links.get('href'))
```

What can i do?

Comment: could you include the relevant code in the question, in a minimal sample ? The error happens because you concatenate two queries in one statement, instead of checking if the first query actually found  something. the `try and except` pattern could help but we lack details about why it's looping like this.

Comment: @PRMoureu edited sir, you are right, forgive me for my mistake..

Comment: Seemingly `soup.find('div', class_='live-matches')` is `None`. So maybe you can attribute it to a variable and check this variable, before starting your for loop. When you check `links` within the loop, it is already too late.

Comment: Hmmmm, that is a way honestly. I couldn't think it. Thank you, i'll try, i'll write the results.

Comment: You should also include the full traceback of your error message, makes it easier to locate the problem.

Comment: It gives error from this line. I know it.

Comment: @Mr.T worked. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're chaining the calls to `.find()` and `find_all()` in

`for links in soup.find('div', class_='live-matches').find_all('a'):`

which makes it impossible to catch an error or `NoneType` in the first `.find()`.

You could do something like this instead:

```
div = soup.find('div', class_='live-matches')
if div is not None:
    for link in div.find_all("a"):
        if link is None:
            continue
        matchlinks_lm.append('https://hltv.org' + links.get('href'))
```